# Xargs and wc -c

Tags: xargs

I have something like this:

```
  grep -v ">" $subfolder/assembly/contigs_1L.fasta | xargs -d \n wc   >> $subfolder/N50_analysis/NC_len.txt
```

With this I want, from a fasta files, remove the identifiers, and then I would like to count for each line the characters of that line.

xargs does what it is supposed to, split after the \n but it wouldn't count. If I do it without the \n, then averything is in just one big line.

EDIT:

Input

```
>C1
AGATGATGAGGATGAGATTGACTACGATCGATCGATGCATCGATCGGCATCGATCGACTGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGTACGATCGGCTACGCGCGATCGACGCGCGCGATCGATCGATCGTCGATCGGCGCGCTACGATCG

>C2
AGATGATGAGGATGAGATTGACTACGATCGATCGATGCATCGATCGGCATCGATCGACTGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGTACGATCGGCTACGCGCGATCGACGCGCGCGATCGATCGATCGTCGATCGGCGCGCTACGATCG
```

I only need the length of the sequence of AGCT, so I am taking (grep) everything that doesn't start with >, in the file. Then I want to count the length of each sequence independently, so at the end I get something like this:

```
 150
 100
  .
  .
  .
  Cn
```

Comment: It would make it easier to help you if you showed us a sample of your input, along with the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -v ">" testfile | awk '{ print length }' >> charcount.txt
```

may be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Take your input file for example:

```sh
cat >input.txt <<EOS
>C1
AGATGATGAGGATGAGATTGACTACGATCGATCGATGCATCGATCGGCATCGATCGACTGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGTACGATCGGCTACGCGCGATCGACGCGCGCGATCGATCGATCGTCGATCGGCGCGCTACGATCG

>C2
AGATGATGAGGATGAGATTGACTACGATCGATCGATGCATCGATCGGCATCGATCGACTGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGATCGTACGATCGGCTACGCGCGATCGACGCGCGCGATCGATCGATCGTCGATCGGCGCGCTACGATCG
EOS
```

### GNU

```sh
grep -v '>' input.txt |
  tr -s '\n' |
  xargs -d '\n' -n1 sh -c 'printf %s "$@" | wc -c' sh
```

```
148
148
```

### BSD

```sh
grep -v '>' input.txt |
  tr '\n' '\0' | tr -s '\0' |
  xargs -0 -n1 sh -c 'printf %s "$@" | wc -c' sh
```

```
     148
     148
```

### Explanation

1. `tr -s` is required because there are empty lines in the input file that would cause `xargs` generating empty strings as arguments.
2. There is no `-d` flag for BSD `xargs`, an idiomatic solution is to combine it with `tr`.
3. We use `printf` instead of `echo` because the latter prints an extra trailing new line character.
4. We use `printf %s "$@"` instead of `printf "$@"` to prevent escaping characters.
5. When using `sh -c`, an extra argument is required for `$0`. Here we use `sh` but you can use any other sensible names.

   > -c string If the -c option is present, then commands are read from string.  If there are arguments after the string, they  are  assigned  to  the
   > positional parameters, starting with $0.